# Visualising redis storage

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

My Redis is filling up rather quickly and I am trying to find a way to visualise what is taking up the space.

Is there a tool or command that will help me visualise whats taking up the storage? Ideally, I would like to know:

1. Key prefix by storage size
2. Key prefix key count

(An option that will work only on Azure will also be suitable as we are using Azure as our Cache storage)

Comment: Redis Desktop Manager is a great and free tool to visualize content in redis clusters. It can be installed on Win, MacOS and Linux and is able to connect with local or remote Redis instance.

Comment: Thanks, but it only shows me the number of keys in queue but not overall storage size and no visualization on whats taking up the needed space.